# How to get Channel Category id with YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels

Its quite easy to get channels assigned to category but i want to get Category for Channel. Is possible to get channel category ID for specific channel ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a straightforward way to do this, though this seems like a reasonable request for an optional field (not all channels may be categorized). I've filed a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5393) for you.

In the meantime, perhaps you may want to explore the topics API. When listing a channel for topicDetails, the [API returns a list of Freebase topic IDs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#resource). These topic IDs map to very specific Freebase entities that can give you far more detailed information about what the channel is about. For instance, a movie trailer about The Dark Knight Returns may return MIDs (Freebase IDs) that map to "movie trailer", Christopher Nolan (the director), "action movie", "Batman", and other entities that we believe the video is about. Check out our [topic search sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#search_by_topic) for more information.